# Missing titlebar on javafx app, with OpenJFX

Tags: java, javafx, openjfx

I'm currently building an application with OpenJDK 11 and OpenJFX. It compiles just fine, and starts, but there is no titlebar, and if I click close to the edge of the app, it registers as a click on whatever window is behind it.

I am using IntelliJ IDEA, and it took a while to figure out how to even use OpenJFX with it. Anyhow, here's the system details:

I'm running elementary OS 5.0 Juno (based off of Ubuntu 18.04, everything is GTK)
IntelliJ IDEA (Community) 2018 installed as a snap.
OpenJFX SDK downloaded from here: [OpenJFX from Gluon](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/)

I've just made a new JavaFX app, and added the dir /javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib/ to external libraries, and then went to run -> edit configurations and added VM options `--module-path <path>/javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.base`

The controller and everything seems to work, but the resulting window looks like this: [image: JavaFX no border or Titlebar]

Does someone know just what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you try with `-Djdk.gtk.version=2`? See possibly related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53333364/drag-and-drop-working-differently-in-java-11-vs-java-8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [José Pereda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3956070/jos%C3%A9-pereda)

It was exactly that which fixed it. See the question he linked for details: [problems with gtk3 and javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53333364/drag-and-drop-working-differently-in-java-11-vs-java-8)

Anyhow, in intelliJ it's solved by going to Run -> Configurations and adding `-Djdk.gtk.version=2` to the 'VM Options'

Comment: You can file a bug for this issue as well: https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues