# Why is title bar missing in my javafx application?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

public class Hello extends  Application{

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("hellofxml.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root,500,500);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("hello world");
   // stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    System.out.println("hello");
}
```

}

The output of this code gives me a simple window without any close, minimize , maximize buttons, in other words a titleless window

I want to know where the problem

images links are

https://ibb.co/5YNfR1G
https://ibb.co/Hq9pM0S

fxml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" fx:controller="Hello.HellofxmlController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="ok_btn" layoutX="238.0" layoutY="174.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="ok" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Can you show us `hellofxml.fxml` file?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" fx:controller="Hello.HellofxmlController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="ok_btn" layoutX="238.0" layoutY="174.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="ok" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>

Comment: There's an [edit] link below the question. Please use that one to provide code; however in this case I'm pretty sure the issue is not related to the fxml. It looks like the stage style is still transparent. Try clean&rebuild the project. Btw: do not provide screenshots to code, but post the code as text instead, unless there's an issue that can only be seen in a screenshot.

Comment: if you are new to SO please take a [tour] and see how to ask a [mcve]. also never add pictures of code instead of pasting it for readability

Comment: thanks for the suggestion

Comment: try `primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);`

Comment: just that i understand this right: you want a normal stage?

Comment: @fuggerjaki61 it is still having the same problem

Comment: Sout(stage.getStyle()) produces output Decorated  but the window does not seems decorated.

Comment: This is a known issue with GTK3 and JavaFX and is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372200/missing-titlebar-on-javafx-app-with-openjfx)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with GTK3 and JavaFX and is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372200/missing-titlebar-on-javafx-app-with-openjfx)