# OpenJFX 11 creates undecorated windows on unix

Tags: java, javafx, java-11, openjfx

I am using OpenJFX 11 and set it up according to the documentation here:

https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx

I used their HelloFX example and compiled it like this:

`cromon@cromon-elementary:~/temp$ /opt/java/latest/bin/javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls HelloFX.java`

This works fine, also running it in theory works:

`cromon@cromon-elementary:~/temp$ /opt/java/latest/bin/java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls HelloFX`

No issues so far. However the created window is undecorated (i.e. has no system menu, only the content area, see screenshot below for an example). I think thats not how it should be. Is anyone having similar issues?

OS information:

```
NAME="elementary OS"
VERSION="5.0 Juno"
```

Java information:

```
cromon@cromon-elementary:/opt$ /opt/java/latest/bin/java -version
openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)
```

And according to the window from `HelloFX`: "Hello, JavaFX 11.0.1, running on Java 11.0.1"

[image]

And here is an example from Swing:

```
val frame = JFrame()
frame.title = "I have a system menu and everything"
frame.preferredSize = Dimension(500, 300)
frame.pack()
frame.isVisible = true
```

[image]

Comment: I have added a JavaFX and a Swing screenshot for comparison

Comment: Do you mean window title bar?

Comment: Exactly, in the screenshots the area with "I have a system menu and everything" in it which is missing in the javafx screenshot.

Comment: Possibly related to a gtk issue, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53351433/3956070)

Comment: Thats it! Funny enough this program is going to be a less platform dependent launcher for a c++ gtk3 application I am working on :)

Comment: Please go forward and add it as an answer!

Comment: @Cromon rather close as duplicate?

Comment: Guess I was too slow, should have answered it myself, then it would have an answer now :). Personally I generally dislike the idea of the duplicates as a reader when I encounter a question via google etc. Always means I have to read the other question and the answer and understand it to figure out if it really answers the "duplicate" question, if it even is a duplicate. Much simpler for future readers if the relevant parts are repeated. In this case it is probably ok, with the comment from José its clear which part is a duplicate even if the question is unrelated.